# What permissions are required, which allow the volume info to be included with the Windows dir cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, active-directory, dir

I'm trying to figure out what permissions are required that would allow a user's account to see the volume information when they run the dir command in a cmd terminal.

This is what the user is seeing:

```
 C:\Cartridges>dir /al
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F903-96F1

 Directory of C:\Cartridges

08/10/2011  09:53 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0010-01 [..]
04/08/2011  08:39 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-01 [\??\Volume{5ea29886-5bd1-45f6-ba68-abcde1234c4a}\]
07/28/2011  09:19 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-05 [..]
08/16/2011  08:40 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-06 [..]
09/26/2011  02:46 PM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-16 [..]
11/09/2011  10:56 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-17 [..]
11/18/2011  04:57 PM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-18 [..]
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              14 Dir(s)  138,044,940,288 bytes free
```

This is what the domain administrator is seeing:

```
 C:\Cartridges>dir /al
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F903-96F1

 Directory of C:\Cartridges

08/10/2011  09:53 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0010-01 [\??\Volume{6ef57859-c291-45f6-ae05-abcde1234c4a}\]
04/08/2011  08:39 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-01 [\??\Volume{5ea29886-5bd1-45f6-ba68-abcde1234c4a}\]
07/28/2011  09:19 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-05 [\??\Volume{bf68b7bc-5969-45f6-8602-abcde1234c4a}\]
08/16/2011  08:40 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-06 [\??\Volume{1945d928-a345-45f6-95ec-abcde1234c4a}\]
09/26/2011  02:46 PM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-16 [\??\Volume{1945d9e6-a345-45f6-95ec-abcde1234c4a}\]
11/09/2011  10:56 AM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-17 [\??\Volume{0987dab8-0484-11e1-af7d-abcde1234c4a}\]
11/18/2011  04:57 PM    <JUNCTION>     003-0011-18 [\??\Volume{0987df91-0484-11e1-af7d-abcde1234c4a}\]
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              14 Dir(s)  138,044,887,040 bytes free
```

NOTE: This is on a system that's in a AD domain.

Comment: not a programming question, please try  http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. This was indeed a permissions problem. Initially we weren't sure if it was a policy issue -OR- something to do with the UAC. In the end we needed to add a group that the user was a member of to the top level directory, C:\Cartridges. The permissions on the group needed to be:

- Read & Execute
- List folder contents
- Read

These seemed to be the minimum set that allowed the Volume strings to be displayed correctly.